# Proving following regular expressions equal to one another?

Tags: computer-science, regular-language, regular-expressions

How would I go about proving the following two regular expressions are equal to one another:
$$
    ( a + b )^* a ( a + b )^* b( a + b )^* = (a + b)^* ab(a + b)^*
$$
I can "see" why they are equal to one another because the second $( a + b )^*$ is a redundant term as the expression will always have an $ab$ together. But how can I formalize this and show, in general, that this is true ?

Comment: What does $+$ stand for? Alternative?

Comment: It's the "or" operator. The alternative is the "and" which is just two letter next to one another.

Comment: Note: This has been crossposted to CS.SE, where it has received 1 answer. That can be found [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/52853/proving-following-regular-expressions-equal-to-one-another). Do not crosspost to different sites at the same time, as it encourages wasted effort and duplication of answers.

Comment: @mixedmath No, it encourages mixed efforts with different approaches to the same problem. And it seems this website brought lot more clearer answers than did the site dedicated to computer science. If I hadn't cross posted, would I have gotten them ?

Comment: I am informing you of site policy. For more, you can read [the Meta.SE faq question on crossposting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/205676). Do not crosspost in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general method is to convert the two regular expressions to a finite automaton each and compare those.

In detail:

- Convert a regular expression to a non-deterministic finite automaton (NFA), e.g. via  [Thompson's construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson's_construction)
- Convert a NFA to a deterministic finite automaton (DFA) via [power set construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction)
- Apply [DFA minimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization) to a given DFA to get a unique DFA.

Here we might get away with naming
\begin{align}
L_1 &= (a+b)^* a (a+b)^* b (a+b)^* \\
L_2 &= (a+b)^* ab (a+b)^*
\end{align}
and first noting
$$
L_1 \supseteq L_2
$$
as the middle part $(a+b)^*$ of the $L_1$ contains the empty word $\epsilon$.

For equality we need to show 
$$
L_1 \subseteq L_2
$$
as well. Let $w = xuy \in L_1$, such that $u$ is accepted by the middle part $(a+b)^*$. Obviously $u \in \{a,b\}^*$.

If $u = \epsilon$ then $w = xy \in L_2$, as $x \in (a+b)^*a$ and $y \in b(a+b)^*$.

Otherwise we assume $u = bu'$ with $u' \in \{a,b\}^*$. We note that $y'= b u' y \in b(a+b)^*$. So we have $w = xy' \in L_2$

Else $u = au'$ with $u' \in \{a,b\}^*$ then $x'=xa \in (a+b)^*a$ as well and we could consider the smaller problem instance $u'$ for $w=x'u'y$.
As $u$ was finite, we will end up in the first case, if $u$ consisted of $a$ symbols only, or with a reduced $u = bv$, thus the second case.

This showed that $L_1 \subseteq L_2$ together with the initial $L_1 \subseteq L_2$ we claim equality $L_1 = L_2$.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how formal you want to be. Letting the two languages be $L_1$ and $L_2$, I’d take it as evident that $L_2$ is the set of words over $\{a,b\}$ that contain $ab$ as a subword. It’s also clear that $L_1\supseteq L_2$, since $a(a+b)^*b$ generates $ab$. Thus, it suffices to show that $L_1\subseteq L_2$, which can be done by showing that every word generated by $a(a+b)^*b$ contains $ab$ as a subword.

This is quite easy. Suppose that $w$ is generated by $a(a+b)^*b$. Let $w=c_1\ldots c_n$, where $c_k\in\{a,b\}$ for $k=1,\ldots,n$, $c_1=a$, and $c_n=b$; clearly $n\ge 2$. Let $m\in\{1,\ldots,n-1\}$ be maximal such that $c_m=a$; then $c_{m+1}=b$, and $w=xaby$ for some $x\in\{a,b\}^*$ and $y\in\{b\}^*$, as desired.

Answer (score 0):

There's a method that's simpler than dealing with NFA's. Brzozowski's method of regular expression derivatives (see [this paper](https://www.mpi-sws.org/~turon/re-deriv.pdf)) constructs a DFA for any regular expression, and it handles booleans nicely. So, given two regular expressions $r_1$ and $r_2$, you can apply Brzozowski's construction to get a DFA for $r_1 \wedge \lnot r_2$ (to see what's matched by $r_1$ but not $r_2$) or even $r_1\iff r_2$ to see if they're equivalent. Once you have the DFA it's a quick depth-first search to see whether any accept states can be reached, but it can be easier than that. I just ran the algorithm on your examples to get a DFA for the regex $(r_1\wedge\lnot r_2)\vee(r_2\wedge\lnot r_1)$, the symmetric difference. The DFA returned had no accept states, so $r_1$ and $r_2$ are equivalent.